# Misunderstanding with enums in Swift

Tags: swift, string, enums

I have enum with cities that looks like

```
enum Cities: String {
    case la = "Los Angeles"
    case ta = "Tel Aviv"
    case ny  = "New York"
}
```

And I need to pass sting with city name to one of functions that is waiting for NSString

so this code is not working and I don't understand why

```
let selectedCity = Cities.ny
myFunc(city : selectedCity)
```

I get error "*Cannot convert value of type 'Cities' to expected argument type 'String!'*"

Xcode is suggesting me to use Cities.ny.rawValue as selectedCity.

Comment: Did you try Xcode's suggestion?

Comment: That seems reasonable.  You've provided strings as the underlying representation for the various cases.

Comment: FWIW it' a common mistake to write your enums plural, yet you should write them singular ie `City` not `Cities`. Just look at `UIColor`...it's not `UIColors`... City is a type, UIColor is a type. Cities/Colors aren't meaningful types

Comment: @Hamish, I just wanted to understand why

Comment: @Honey, I will think about this idea next time I need to create enumeration in Swift.  But I also think that it can't be called as a "mistake". Not only because it is "common" used. But also because UIColor is not enumeration - it is a class as I know. Right now "Cities" looks for me essential to be name of enumeration of cities, but I will think about it.

Comment: @moonvader you're right. UIColor is a class not an enum. But the idea about enums...just look on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)...rarely you'll find an enum that is plural.  However among developers it's a common mistake. It being common/uncommon doesn't make it right. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify raw value to use the string literal, because without that you are just referring to the enum itself.

```
let selectedCity = Cities.ny.rawValue
```

Answer (score 4):

### Swift is strongly typed

So when you pass a value to a function argument the compiler checks that it is of the correct type.

### Example

Let's declare a function that receive an `Int` as parameter

```
func giveMeYourAge(n: Int) {

}
```

And now let's try to invoke that function passing something that is NOT an Int

```
giveMeYourAge(n: "Hello World")
```

Now the compiler gets angry with us ☠️

> error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'
>   giveMeYourAge(n: "Hello World")

And it is right (of course). Infact it is telling us that we cannot pass a `String` to a function that expects an `Int`indeed.

### Your code

When you declare you enum (let's call it `City` as properly suggested by *@Honey*) you create a new type `City`.

```
enum City: String {
    case la = "Los Angeles"
    case ta = "Tel Aviv"
    case ny  = "New York"
}
```

`City` is something **TOTALLY DIFFERENT** from a `String`.
And we cannot use `City` in place of a `String` or viceversa. (Just like in the previous example `Int` was totally different from `String`).

So if you have a function that expects a `String` as parameter

```
func myFunc(city : String) {
    // ...
}
```

of course you **won't** be able to pass an value of type `City` to it.

### Wait! What about Polymorphism?

Now let's look at this code

```
class Animal { }
class Dog: Animal { }

func feed(animal: Animal) {

}

let dog = Dog()

feed(animal: dog)
```

**Why does this code compile???**

This is called polymorphism. When we write

```
 class Dog: Animal { }
```

we define a new type (`Dog`) that is more specific than `Animal`.

**Polymorphism** does allow us to pass to a function that expects an `Animal` as param, something that is more specific (like a `Dog`).

**However polymorphism has nothing to do with your example.** Even if the syntax is similar.

When you define an enum using this syntax

```
enum City: String { ... }
```

- You are **NOT** defining a subtype of String.
- You are **NOT** creating something more specific than a String.
- You are **NOT** using polymorphism.

Instead you are simply creating a new type `City` that has an instance property (`rawValue`) of type `String`.

Answer (score 3):

I have better solution, which is much more reasonable... therefore you do this:

```
enum Cities {

    case la
    case ta
    case ny

  var cityString: String{
    switch self{
    case la:
    return "Los Angeles"
    case ta:
    return "Tel Aviv"
    case ny:
    return "New York"
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to call just this:

```
let selectedCity = Cities.ny.cityString
```

the reason behind me voting over other ideas is that rawValues should be used for recognizing the case, not for getting the values of them... But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: Looks to me like an update error waiting to happen when you change the raw value and not the switch value.  If you're going to do this, remove the raw value type and just make it `enum Cities { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It's like you're trying to access a class instance, rather that the property of the instance. It won't work. Specifically what you're trying here is accessing the enum itself which is incorrect. You should access its `rawValue` *property*.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html):

> You access the raw value of an enumeration case with its rawValue
>   **property**:

```
enum Planet: Int {
    case mercury = 1, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune
}

let earthsOrder = Planet.earth.rawValue
// earthsOrder is 3
```